# Losing values in struct array after leaving for loop in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I am about 5 days into C programming and I am having a bit of trouble understanding what exactly is happening in my code. I populate an array of room structs on the heap the rooms each have integer values I fill with user input right after I allocate space. There is an array of creature structs inside each room struct. I fill the fields inside each room with int values from stdin, however after I fill them and leave the for loop the values seem to reset and I get random values in their place similarly to when I allocate the memory on the heap beforehand. Why I am so confused is that when I fill my creature_array with the values from stdin I do it almost in the same process and everything looks fine and those values can be accessed where needed in my game. Any help is greatly appreciated thanks! My code for filling rooms and creatures is below.

```
typedef struct {
   int type;
   int room_number;
   int creat_number;
} creature;

typedef struct {
   struct room *north; //refernce to neighbor
   struct room *south;
   struct room *east;
   struct room *west;
   int n,s,e,w;
   int room_name, state;
   creature creature_array[10];
} room; 

void addCreature(int rm, int t, int cm) {
   int i = 0;
   int f = 0;
  for (; i < 10; i++) {
      if (ptr[rm].creature_array[i].type != 0 && ptr[rm].creature_array[i].type != 1 && ptr[rm].creature_array[i].type !=2) {
         ptr[rm].creature_array[i].creat_number = cm;
         ptr[rm].creature_array[i].type = t;
         ptr[rm].creature_array[i].room_number = rm;
         break;
      } else {
         f++;
         if (f == 9) {
            printf("Room ");
            printf("%d", ptr[rm].room_name);
            printf(" is full.\n");
         }
       }
     }
   }

int main(void) {
   setbuf(stdout, NULL);
   int state, north, south, east, west;
   printf("Welcome!\nHow many rooms?\n");
   int num_r;
   scanf("%d", &num_r);
   ptr = (room *)malloc(num_r * (sizeof (room)));
   int i = 0;
for (; i < num_r; i++) {
      scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &state, &north, &south, &east, &west);
      ptr[i].room_name=i;
      ptr[i].state = state;
      ptr[i].n=north;
      ptr[i].s=south;
      ptr[i].e=east;
      ptr[i].w=west;
   }
   printf("How many creatures?\n");
   int room_num, type, creat_num;
   int num_of_c;
   scanf("%d", &num_of_c);
   int p = 0;
   int PC_count = 0;
   int creat_count = 0;
 for (; p < num_of_c; p++) {
      creat_num = creat_count++;
      scanf("%d %d", &type, &room_num);
      if (type == 0) {
         PC_count++;
         if (PC_count > 1) {
            printf("Too many PC players\n");
            exit(0);
         }
         addCreature(room_num,type,creat_num);
         pc = &ptr[room_num].creature_array[p];
      } else {
         addCreature(room_num,type,creat_num);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this actually compile? Looks like a bunch of extra } on that one line

Comment: I looked at that [scary], but they all line up, although indentation would help. (if,else,for,function). However I haven't yet found the definition for `ptr`, which appears to be used globally, but should probably be passed as a parameter.

Comment: I apologize for the wacky spacing. I have the pointer declared globally as: room * ptr;

Comment: Don't apologize, simply edit it and format it properly. That makes it easy for people wanting to help you to actually understand the problem. It also makes things a lot easier for you.

Comment: FWIW, this: `if (ptr[rm].creature_array[i].type != 0||1||2)` looks suspicious. It is probably not what you want. You probably want `type` to be neither 0, 1 or 2. This is the wrong way to express that. Try `if (ptr[rm].creature_array[i].type != 0 && ptr[rm].creature_array[i].type != 1 && ptr[rm].creature_array[i].type != 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
if (ptr[rm].creature_array[i].type != 0||1||2)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (ptr[rm].creature_array[i].type != (0||1||2) )
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (ptr[rm].creature_array[i].type != 1 )
```

Is that what you wanted?

I suspect you wanted:

```
if ( (ptr[rm].creature_array[i].type != 0) &&
     (ptr[rm].creature_array[i].type != 1) &&
     (ptr[rm].creature_array[i].type != 2) )
```

Comment: But that is always `true`. You want `&&`.

Comment: I actually expect he meant it is not 0, 1, or 2, so that would be: `...type != 0 && ...type != 1 && ...type != 2`.

Comment: @Tordek and Rudy, makes sense.

Comment: Yes I will edit my work I feel like that does prevent potential issues thanks! What I still don't understand is why all the fields in my room structs vanish after I leave that for loop

Answer (score 0):

`addCreature()` uses uninitialized values of `ptr[room_num].creature_array`.